# In package PerformanceAnalytics /apply.fromstart, use given function as parameter

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

In package PerformanceAnalytics `apply.fromstart`, when I want to use function `CHANGE` which form `tidyquant` package, it's failed. How fix it ? Thanks!

```
library(tidyquant)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
 data(managers)
 apply.fromstart(managers[,1,drop=FALSE], FUN="tidyquant::CHANGE")
```